# Save file from an Entity from a collection form

Tags: symfony

I have a collection form called Paragraphe with a text and a file (an Image):

```
class ParagrapheType extends AbstractType {
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
{
    $builder
        ->add('text')
        ->add('image', FileType::class, ['mapped'=>false, 'required'=>false])
```

And it's inside another form called Article.
Here, how I add a Paragraphe inside formulaire.html.twig of Article (I just followed [How to Embed a Collection of Forms](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html#how-to-embed-a-collection-of-forms) from the official Symfony doc) :

```
<h3>Paragraphes:</h3>
{# the data-index attribute is required for the JavaScript code below #}
<ul class="paragraphes" data-index="{{ (formArticle.paragraphes|length) > 0 ? formArticle.paragraphes|last.vars.name + 1 : 0 }}" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(formArticle.paragraphes.vars.prototype)|e( 'html_attr' ) }}"></ul>
<button type="button" class="add_item_link" data-collection-holder-class="paragraphes">Add an paragraphe</button>
<script>
//event listener sur le bouton document.querySelectorAll('.add_item_link') ➡️ adds a new Paragraphe form on the Article form when push the button⤵️
const addFormToCollection = (e) => { const collectionHolder =
document.querySelector('.' + e.currentTarget.dataset.collectionHolderClass);

const item = document.createElement('li');
item.innerHTML = collectionHolder .dataset .prototype .replace( /__name__/g, collectionHolder.dataset.index );
collectionHolder.appendChild(item);
collectionHolder.dataset.index++; };

document
    .querySelectorAll('.add_item_link')
    .forEach(btn => { btn.addEventListener("click", addFormToCollection) });
```

**Here what I try** to save my Image in my ArticleControler.php:

```
foreach ($form->get('paragraphes')->getData() as $paragraphe) {
   $imageParagraphe= $paragraphe->get('image')->getData(); //get() method doesn't exist so I don't know how to get the file.
   if($imageParagraphe){
       $fileNameImageParagraphe = $articleSlug . uniqid() . '.' . $imageParagraphe->guessExtension();
       //move the image as parametred in service.yaml
       try {
           $imageParagraphe->move($this->getParameter('article_images'), $fileNameImageParagraphe);
       } catch (FileException $e) {
           $this->addFlash('erreur', "Image cannot be uploaded.");
       }
       $paragraphe->setImage($fileNameImageParagraphe);
   } else $paragraphe->setImage($imageParagraphe);
}
```

As my comment says, I didn't find a way to get the file inside the second form. Did I need to do it from my script inside my twig?

Comment: I found a new method to do what I want but I have to read, understand and implement. [Events and Event Listeners](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html#creating-an-event-listener)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69537872/get-the-file-object-in-the-forms-controller-from-a-javascript-array-collection) question, I was able to find that I needed to loop through $formParagraphe and not through $formParagraphe->getData().

Here my updated contoller:

```
foreach ($form->get('paragraphes') as $formParagraphe) {
  $imageParagraphe= $formParagraphe->get('image')->getData();
  $paragraphe= $formParagraphe->getData();
  if($imageParagraphe){
    $fileNameImageParagraphe = $articleSlug . uniqid() . '.' . $imageParagraphe->guessExtension();
    //déplace l'image dans le dossier paramétré dans service.yaml
    try {
      $imageParagraphe->move($this->getParameter('article_images'), $fileNameImageParagraphe );
    } catch (FileException $e) {
      $this->addFlash('erreur', "L'image n'a pas pu être uploadé.");
    }
    $paragraphe->setImage($fileNameImageParagraphe);
  } else $paragraphe->setImage($imageParagraphe);
}
if ($article->getSlug() !== $articleSlug) {
  $article->setSlug($articleSlug);
}
```

PS: I'm gonna update this when I find out how to keep the old Image in the form...